# How to build my library project(aar) with android source code?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, aar

I have a custom android system image, I'd like to build my aar project(lib1.aar) into our android source code. My app app1, app2 will use this lib1.aar as their dependencies. I used below Android.mk file to make it, but I got 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' error since my code imported it like calling string from resource file.

```
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := lib1
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled 
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

My question is how to write Android.mk file to compile my lib1.aar as a system lib to let my app use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include your .aar libs with these lines:

`LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES:= <aar alias> 
 include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := <aar alias>:libs/<lib file>.aar
 include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)`

Please, be aware of your projects and lib's minSDKVersion.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I want to build my source code with Android image source code. not the aar one which packed by android studio.